# html frame only allow horizontal resize ie8

Tags: html, resize, frame, frameset

I have created a web page with 2 framesets:

```
<frameset id='frameset1'  cols="30%,70%">

<frameset id='frameset2'  rows="15%,85%" frameborder="0" border="0">
<frame id="headerframe" name="frame3" src="source1" scrolling="no">
<frame id="contentsframe" name="frame1" src="source2">
</frameset>

<frame name="maincontent" src="source3">
</frameset>
```

I'm trying to make it so that the user can't resize the frames in frameset2 vertically, but can still resize horizontally. Is there a way of doing this in ie8? I have tried using the CSS resize property but I can't get it to work in this browser.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the files source1 and source2:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
</style>
```